# How to find the central meeting point for the following cities distributed in a 2D coordinate system?

Tags: arrays, geometry, coordinates, distance, coordinate-systems

You have been given the following arrays:

```
x[n] - x[i] denotes the x coordinates of ith city
y[n] - y[i] denotes the y coordinate of the ith city
p[n] - p[i] denotes the population of the ith city
```

Given the coordinates and the population of each city spread in a 2D plane, goal is to find the perfect meeting point of all the `n` cities such that the travel cost for all the cities to reach the point is **minimum**.

```
Let that meeting point be (x,y)
Travel cost for city i having coordinates (x[i], y[i]) and population of p[i] is:
p[i] * (abs(x[i] - x) + abs(y[i] - y)), abs() is the absolute value, and (abs(x[i] - x) + abs(y[i] - y)) is the distance to reach (x,y) from (x[i], y[i])
```

I don't exactly remember the constraints, but I guess it was `1 <= n <= 100,000`

**My Approach**
I initially thought that this problem was analogous to finding the Center of Gravity of discrete mass distributions, where the mass was analogous to the population, and the central meeting point was the CG. And since it was the 'Center', the total travel cost should be minimum.

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    x += x[i]*p[i];
    y += y[i]*p[i];
    sum  += p[i];
}
x /= sum;
y /= sum;
```

Then calculating the cost:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cost += p[i]*(abs(x[i] - x) + abs(y[i] - y));
}
```

But then I found out that although it passed the example test cases, it failed the rest. And i figured out if these were the corresponding values of the arrays

```
x[] = {3,1}
y[] = {3,1}
p[] = {2,1}
```

Then CG would have been (2,2) with cost 6, but if instead the meeting point was at (3,3), the cost could have been 4, which is minimum.
So, is there something as a center of this distribution, and if/if not, how to find the meeting point, considering the given constraint?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really follow your approach. A huge hint is that distance is `di = sqrt((x-xi)^2 + (y-yi)^2)` and you are trying to mimimze the sum (over `i`) of `di * pi`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it, but distance between two points, is to be calculated as  (x-xi) + (y-yi)

Comment: oh, that's in the problem description?